# How to render asymptom code?

Tags: geometry

How do I render the below asymptom code in google doc? Is there a way?

```
    [asy]
    size(75);
    pair A,B,C,D;
    B = (0,0);
    A = (0.4,-0.8);
    C =(-0.4,-0.8);
    D= (0,-0.8);
    draw(D--B--A--C--B);
    label("$B$",B,N);
    label("$D$",D,S);
    label("$A$",A,SE);
    draw(rightanglemark(A,D,B,3.5));
    label("$C$",C,SW);
[/asy]
```

Comment: This seems to be asympt**ote** code, not asymptom (I'm not aware of any software called asymptom). Please update your question and title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no support for asymptote in Google doc. However, since asymptote supports rendering to an image file, you could just render to a `.png` (or any other format of your liking).

[The documentation](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) suggests using the `-f` flag for this, so you should try

```
asy -f png yourfilename
```

Afterwards, you can copy and paste the image into your document.

Comment: Is there a way that a plugin can be developed to do this? if yes how?

Comment: When there's a will, there's a way. You could take a look at [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs). However, this will likely mean that you'll have to implement the compiler for asymptote yourself (or have it hosted on a different) server, so if you don't want to waste a lot of time, I recommend you to stay with copy and paste.